# returning lists in one dart file to another dart file

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using lists to create inkwell buttons. I want to put the lists in a separate dart file and import the file into the files where I use the lists. I don't know how to import the lists.

https://pastebin.com/mf0kvsGu

I made a dart file to put the lists into.

https://prnt.sc/ndu736 "Lists error"

```dart
 void _loginPressed() {
    // these handlers are called whenever the user tries to login, resend password or create an account
    print('The use wants to login with $_email and $_password');
    //if (_email == ""&& _password == "") {
    ButtonsLists();
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => BrowsePage(buttonList)));
    //}
  }
```

```dart
class BuyItem extends StatelessWidget {
  BuyItem(this.name, this.image);

  final String name;
  final String image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ButtonsLists();

    return InkWell(
      child: Card(
        child: GridTile(
......
```

http://prntscr.com/ndu7rc "Import error"

The code works if I don't have the lists in a separate file and instead have them where the ButtonsLists(); is at.

Comment: Could you supply more information? I see you just create a new `ButtonLists` instance without using it inside the build method. It would help if you added both the working code and the non-working code.

Comment: here is the working code for the login page
https://pastebin.com/A9MwM887
ignore the imports

i want to separate the list and import the list into this
"non working login page" https://pastebin.com/TsPx54eQ 
https://pastebin.com/mf0kvsGu

Comment: i am using the lists twice so i want to be able to import the lists into both dart files where the lists are being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `import` will only import you the class written in the file you're referring to. More precisely, The ability to create instances of the class in the imported `Dart` file

**To solve your problem**

1- Initialize your lists globally inside `ButtonsLists` class. (before the `Build()` method). I'd rather to declare them `final`

2- Fill your lists with data as you like in the `Build()` method

3- Create getters to get a copy of your filled lists

4- Create an instance of the `ButtonsLists` class inside the `_LoginPageState` class and call the getter of any list whenever you need

The implementation should be something like this:

```
class ButtonsLists extends StatelessWidget {

final List<MainButtons> _buttonList = new List();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       //Build your lists here
}

List<MainButtons> getMainButtonsList(){
      return _buttonList;
}
```

Then inside `_LoginPageState` class create an instance of the class `ButtonsLists` like this:

`ButtonsLists mLists = new ButtonsLists();`

and call your list anywhere in the class like this:

`mLists.getMainButtonsList();`

Comment: are there any flutter list getters i can read? this is the code so far
https://pastebin.com/ruGrL1yy
all i need to push is buttonList

Comment: @Robot2425 I updated my answer
If you found it helpful, kindly mark it as the correct answer!